# How can I find something I wrote years ago in The Pod Bay?

Tags: support, chat, search

Several years ago I added several messages in The Pod Bay about Arno Penzias and Robert Wilson about their discovery of the cosmic microwave background and their 1978 Nobel prize in Physics.

Linked were videos of an interview with them and I think they were playing a tape recorder of the hiss in the video. It might be BBC footage, I'm not sure.

The context in The Pod Bay was that someone was looking for story for a film script, and I proposed that this would be an interesting one (and still do!)

How can I go about finding those links? Have they scrolled out to the Kuiper belt by now or is there some way to search?

I'm asking because I just saw [Cosmic microwave background and “white dielectric”](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/12343/3869) in History of Science and Math SE and I want to check them to see if there is more about the pigeon-derived “white dielectric” in their microwave horn in the videos or other links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chat has limited search functionality, but it is possible to search for text written by user X in room Y. Here is an example:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=space&user=131397&room=9682

but you can tweak the exact search text in the form at the top of the page.

[image]

Comment: bingo! https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33153481#33153481 verbal imagery of pigeon "output" and all!

Comment: [Done](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/12356/3869)! (video is funny)

Comment: ...and then gets quite serious